# Partitioning existing table in Oracle

Tags: oracle

(Oracle) I'm trying to do an exchange partition on an empty partitioned table to fill it with data from a non-partitioned table. I'm getting the following error and can't find the cause. I'm not 100% certain of the version, I know it < 11g. I'll have to double check and update my post.

```
SQL Error: ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
14097. 00000 -  "column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION"
*Cause:    The corresponding columns in the tables specified in the
           ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION are of different type or size
*Action:   Ensure that the two tables have the same number of columns
           with the same type and size.
```

**What I have tried**

- Verified both tables have same number of columns, order of columns, data types, constraints and indexes
- Verified there are no hidden columns on my newly partitioned empty table
- I have not altered the original table in any way shape or form
- I tried making a copy of the original table and doing the exchange partition with that on the off chance something may be writing to the original table and Oracle doesn't like that.
- I tried using Dbms.Redefine, but don't have the rights to run that and it's not an option for the DBA to grant me rights to that.

**Code**

Create copy of original table:

```
create table foo as select * from LOGGING_EVENT
```

Creating partitioned table

```
create table LOGGING_EVENT_PARTITIONED
(
  TIMESTMP number(20,0) not null,
  FORMATTED_MESSAGE varchar2(4000 BYTE),
  LOGGER_NAME varchar2(254 BYTE) not null,
  LEVEL_STRING varchar2(254 BYTE) not null,
  THREAD_NAME varchar2(254 BYTE),
  REFERENCE_FLAG number(38,0),
  ARG0 varchar2(254 BYTE),
  ARG1 varchar2(254 BYTE),
  ARG2 varchar2(254 BYTE),
  ARG3 varchar2(254 BYTE),
  CALLER_FILENAME varchar2(254 BYTE) not null,
  CALLER_CLASS varchar2(254 BYTE) not null,
  CALLER_METHOD varchar2(254 BYTE) not null,
  CALLER_LINE char(4 BYTE) not null,
  EVENT_ID number(10,0) primary key 
)
partition by range (event_id)
interval(10000)  (
  partition p1 values less than (10000)
);
```

Exchanging partition:

```
alter table LOGGING_EVENT_PARTITIONED
exchange partition p1
with table foo
without validation
update global indexes;
```

Error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-14097: column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION
14097. 00000 -  "column type or size mismatch in ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION"
*Cause:    The corresponding columns in the tables specified in the
           ALTER TABLE EXCHANGE PARTITION are of different type or size
*Action:   Ensure that the two tables have the same number of columns
           with the same type and size.
```

**Verifying original and partitioned tables are the same**

New Partitioned Table
[image: New Partitioned Table]

Original Table
[image: Original Table]

Comment: Look for unused columns in the source table.

Comment: these picture are not useful. Can you show us a `describe foo`  and a `describe LOGGING_EVENT_PARTITIONED`

Comment: why do you file the foo table with a select? Why don't  you  directly fill the LOGGING_EVENT_PARTITIONED with a select from LOGGING_EVENT?

Comment: Is the FOO table same in term of constraints to the LOGGING_EVENT_PARTITIONED table. Particularly NOT NULL Constraint

Comment: If your DBA does not like to grant execute on DBMS_REDEFINITION then ask him/her to partition your table by himself. If he/she still refuse, ask what is his/her job actually.